# How can I get the result by only one sql in MySQL

Tags: mysql

There two mysql table just like table1 and table2. I want get the result by one sql.

```
#table1
c1  c2 //clomun
a   10
b   20
c   30

#table2
c1  c2
a   11
b   21
e   99
```

I want get the result like below.

```
# result
c1   c2
a    21
b    41
c    30
e    99
```

Comment: Alright boy and what have you tried so far? Also we can't easily predict what you want from a single dataset of an expected result without some explanation on what you actually need and why.

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  Stack Overflow is a resource to _help_ you with your problem, but it is not a free coding/homework service.

Comment: "SUM" *ba dum tss*

Comment: Yes, I have try many times. Maybe It's very easy, But  I  have no ability to slove it. Or I have a bad talent.

Comment: No one has bad talent, simply put you're just a bit lazy :3

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
select c1, sum(c2) from
 (
   select c1, c2 from table1
   union all
   select c1, c2 from table2
 ) as total
group by c1
```

Please note that if the columns names are not identical, you will need to give them identical alias names as below:

```
select column1, sum(column2 ) from
 (
   select c1 as column1, c2 as column2 from table1
   union all
   select c1 as column1, c2 as column2  from table2
 ) as total
group by column1
```

Comment: While I appreciate you taking the time to answer, I wish people wouldn't answer questions that blatantly lack any attempt at their own work or even spending the time to ask a decent question.